# CSS Animation with Fade Transition on Slick Slider

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I'm implementing the slick slider and have added a Ken Burn's effect to images using css animation.

I'm getting a jump in the animation before the slide changes - the image seems to go back to its original state. Really I'm after a smooth transition. Any ideas on how to fix?

See Example on Code Pen:
https://codepen.io/katundu/pen/aJJqWv

**JS**

```
  $('.slider').slick({
    draggable: true,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 7000,
    arrows: false,
    dots: true,
    fade: true,
    speed: 500,
    infinite: true,
    cssEase: 'ease-in-out',
    touchThreshold: 100
  })
```

**Slide Show**

```
<div class="slideshow">
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://tesla.uk-cpi.com/login/resources/market-built-environment-3-w1920h1080.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://tesla.uk-cpi.com/login/resources/pipes-w1920h1080.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS and Animation**

```
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  background: #333;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.slideshow {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}
.slideshow * {
  outline: none;
}
.slideshow .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 20px 50px -25px black;
}
.slideshow .slider-track {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1);
  transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1);
}
.slideshow .item {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
.slideshow .item img {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1);
  transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
          transform: scale(1.2);
}
.slideshow .item.slick-active img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
          transform: scale(1);
  -webkit-animation: cssAnimation 8s 1 ease-in-out;
  animation: cssAnimation 8s 1 ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes cssAnimation {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1) translate(0px);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3) translate(0px);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes cssAnimation {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1) translate(0px);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3) translate(0px);
  }
}
```

Comment: -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);transform: scale(1.2); should be 1.3 as in the end of your animation keyframes

Comment: can you give a bit more details as to why?

Comment: animation starts at `scale(1)` (overriding the default `scale(1.2)`) ends at `1.3` - if you want to stay at final state of animation you have to add animation FORWARDS -  `animation 8s 1 ease-in-out forwards`; - but that **will not** help you since the class triggering the animation gets removed on transition to next slide, so it would jump back to default **scale(1.2)** again. - Makes sense?

Comment: Thanks this is really helpful

Comment: For some reason I still get the jump with the image

Comment: it will happen if transition to next frame occurs before animation ends. My advice is - don't use animation, try css transition. I will try to update my answer.

Comment: Ah great - that would certainly be helpful I you think it can be done that way

Comment: it can work that way, problem is that the transition is not triggered with the first image, because there is not a change of class - the "active" class is fired right away... i wonder how could this be worked around

Comment: What about pausing the animation on click using JS?

 object.style.animationPlayState="paused"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your default transform scale is smaller than the end of animation.

Animation final state (forwards) won't help your case, because on the transition to the next slide, class triggering the animation gets removed.

```
.slideshow .item img {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1);
  transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);/*-webkit-transform: scale(1.2);*/
          transform: scale(1.3);/*transform: scale(1.2)*/
}
```

```js
  $('.slider').slick({
    draggable: true,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 7000,
    arrows: false,
    dots: true,
    fade: true,
    speed: 500,
    infinite: true,
    cssEase: 'ease-in-out',
    touchThreshold: 100
  })
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  background: #333;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.slideshow {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}
.slideshow * {
  outline: none;
}
.slideshow .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 20px 50px -25px black;
}
.slideshow .slider-track {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1);
  transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1);
}
.slideshow .item {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
.slideshow .item img {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1);
  transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
          transform: scale(1.3);
}
.slideshow .item.slick-active img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
          transform: scale(1);
  -webkit-animation: cssAnimation 8s 1 ease-in-out forwards;
  animation: cssAnimation 8s 1 ease-in-out forwards;
}

@keyframes cssAnimation {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1) translate(0px);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3) translate(0px);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes cssAnimation {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1) translate(0px);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3) translate(0px);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<div class="slideshow">
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518791841217-8f162f1e1131?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532386236358-a33d8a9434e3?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=978&q=80" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: To make it better, change or remove scale 1.3 to: 
.slideshow .item img {  -webkit-transform: scale(1); transform: scale(1); }